isometries as products of reflections
I am taking a course on geometric transformations in the 2-dimensional Euclidean plane. I have been told that all isometries (length-preserving transformations) are products of reflections about certain lines. I am wondering whether the converse, viz. that all products of reflections are isometries, is true. I am also wondering what information we would need about an isometry to determine which lines are reflected about in the product. I have no idea how to solve any of these, perhaps because I haven't finished the course.

Can you show that the product of two isometries is an isometric? And that a single reflection is an isometry? That’s all you need for your first question.

If you know that a reflection is an isometry, then your first question is straightforward. Any composition of isometries, which are distance preserving transformations, is clearly still a distance preserving transformation.
To answer the second question, the isometries of the plane can be classified into 5 types: identity, reflection, translation, rotation, and glide reflection (which is the composition of a reflection and a translation).
Any non-identity isometry of the plane can be classified using just two conditions: whether it is orientation preserving or reversing and whether it has fixed points. Reversing orientation is like flipping a sheet of paper. Draw a triangle with dark ink on a sheet of paper and label the vertices ABC going clockwise. If you flip the paper, the vertices will now read ACB. A single reflection is an orientation reversing isometry with a line of fixed points at the axis of reflection. A glide reflection is also orientation reversing but has no fixed points.
An even number of reflections will always be orientation preserving (just like how flipping a sheet of paper an even number of times lands you on the same side you started with). Whether or not the resulting isometry is classified as a translation or rotation depends on the fixed points, which in turn depends on the intersection of the axes of reflections.
It turns out that any isometry of the plane can be expressed as the composition of three or fewer reflections. If you convince yourself of this by considering these conditions, I think you will be able to answer your own question.
